# Quartz Crashes At The Of Every Job

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I have a weird problem with Quartz.Net 2.5.0, whenever a job gets executed an exception is being thrown at the Quartz worker thread which I have no means to catch and I couldn't know what causes it and it causes the recurrent jobs to stop executing recurrently 
I'm using Quartz with an ASP.NET web forms website

here's the stack trace

> > Quartz.dll!Quartz.Core.JobRunShell.Run() Line 187   C#
> >         Quartz.dll!Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool.WorkerThread.Run() Line 485    C#
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)    Unknown
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
> >         mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    Unknown
> >         [Native to Managed Transition]

and here's a sample of a job and it's registration

```
public static void StartDriverrsArrivedToPointJob()
{
    ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
    IJobDetail jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create<DriversArrivedToPointJob>().StoreDurably().Build();
    IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
    sched.Start();
    ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create().WithSimpleSchedule(s => s.WithIntervalInMinutes(5)).Build();
    sched.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
}

public class DriversArrivedToPointJob : IJob
{
    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {  
        var driversManager = new DriversManager();
        IEnumerable<Driver> drivers = driversManager.GetAllDriversHeadingToPoints();
        foreach (var driver in drivers)
        {
            var point = driver.MagnetPoint;
            var pointLocation = new Location(point.Lat, point.Lng, LocationType.Degree);
            bool arrived = driversManager.CheckIfDriverArrivedToLocation(driver.DriverId, pointLocation);

            if (!arrived)
                continue;

            driversManager.CheckinDriver(driver.DriverId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is by design that Quartz swallows all exceptions thrown by your jobs. I would guess the exception comes from your job. Please put an `try{} catch{}` in your `Execute()` method and look what is causing it.

Comment: @Rabban I'm aware of that particular characteristic of Quartz but I don't think it comes from the Job the exception gets thrown when the after the debugger attempts to leave the Execute method

Comment: If you are really sure that this doesn't come from your Job, then i see no other possibility than to look in the quartz source to `JobRunShell` at Line 187. I took a brief look under the hood, but the repository is not well organzied. The "Master" branch seems to be the Alpha 3 and the line 187 is empty. And in the "2.x" branch, the line is `endTime = SystemTime.UtcNow();`. Both can't be the reason for the exception. Or the line number is not correct through some compiler optimizations.

Comment: Do you have the build-in logging activated? Maybe there is some more information about this.

Comment: You didn't actually say what the exception is. If you really think the exception is coming from Quartz.Net, you can try enabling internal debugging or even download the source code and step through the code.